# mysql server - update one row - 140 sec

Tags: mysql, time, percona

I have a problem with the SQL server. (percona on centos)
Everything worked fine - to 3 days ago.
We don't know what happened and suddenly it started to crash with 1205 errors - lock transaction - rarely, but it happens.
Today I did a one-record update and the result is below.

What could be the reason?
The server is restarted, the configuration has not been changed for several years. Everything worked fine.
The application code has also not been changed recently.

```
UPDATE exam SET deleted_at = '2022-10-17 10:39:17' WHERE id = 2622814
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 140,978s
```

Comment: I would check your indexes aren't corrupted. Include the mysql.* tables in the optimize process too.

Comment: indexes are ok, i checked this before. optimization process do not change anything, restart server too. 
I send the same command few second later and server make a request in 0,03sec.
I have no idea what's going on anymore

Comment: INFO: I make the same query few minutes later & time was 0,003sec

Comment: Please post your table schema

Comment: https://ibb.co/w4dcnHm - here are screen shot